# Creating a C string array, when reading from file

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, queue, c-strings

im doing a project, where i need to manage a queue of sorts, specifically cars in a car wash. I've found some code online, that allows you to add to queue and manage it, with integer inputs. Is there a way for me to re-write this code, so that it accepts inputs as c strings instead of integers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *front = NULL;
struct node *rear = NULL;

void display();
void enqueue(int);
void dequeue();

int main()
{
    int n, ch;
    do
    {
        printf("\n\nQueue Menu\n1. Add \n2. Remove\n3. Display\n0. Exit");
        printf("\nEnter Choice 0-3? : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter number ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                enqueue(n);
                break;
            case 2:
                dequeue();
                break;
            case 3:
                display();
                break;
        }
    }while (ch != 0);
}

void enqueue(int item)
{
    struct node *nptr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nptr->data = item;
    nptr->next = NULL;
    if (rear == NULL)
    {
        front = nptr;
        rear = nptr;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = nptr;
        rear = rear->next;
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = front;
    printf("\n");
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void dequeue()
{
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nqueue is empty \n");
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *temp;
        temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        printf("\n\n%d deleted", temp->data);
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Where the desired input would be one of these strings;

```
AV96888 VW alm
KD65656 Audi luksus
AX21878 Ford alm
CN32323 VW alm
NB21214 Ford luksus
UM21878 Ford alm
AV54361 Tesla luksus
```

Comment: Yes there is a way. Which part has you stuck? Reading string instead of number? Storing string instead of number? Did you try those two things separatly? (https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) ? Where are you stuck there?

Comment: I think its a combination, im unsure as to how i should use pointers exactly, when reading strings and storing them, and as to what parts of the program i should change, in order for me to read and store strings.

Comment: Yes it is a combination. Which of the parts did you try? Which succeeded? What did you try? You really need to get away from the homework assignment approach to "find it on the net". The goal for the homework is not to provide the teacher with a functionality the need. The goal is that you implement yourself a functionality which the teacher does not actually bother getting from you.

Comment: I've tried some different stuff now, where i've tried to make it read chars instead of integers, but it wont seem to store what i enter into the queue, more specifically, it just keeps going "choice" menu when you press 1, without letting me enter any input to the queue. In addition to that, it enters random integers into the queue, whenever i give it input to add to queue.

Comment: Try parts first. Really. Please take my advice and the advice of what I linked. If "i've tried to make it read chars instead of integers, but it wont seem to store" already fails then drop the queue thing for now and get the simple storing of a single char/"string" working. I recommend to make a question about only that, including a [mre] on only that. If there is no answer on your current question here yet, it is OK to focus this question on that smaller thing (this is not the same as dramatically changing to a different topic, which is frowned upon). You will find help faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data is stored in the node:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

So you just need to change the `int data;` to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Are there a reason you are doing this in C and not c++ ? There, string management is easier.

Comment: Yeah its a mandatory course for my class.. We have to learn c programming for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, you just convert the data to char * and use strdup to store the pointer

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

struct node
{   
    char *data; 
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *front = NULL;
struct node *rear = NULL;

void enqueue(char *item)
{
    struct node *nptr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nptr->data = strdup(item);
    nptr->next = NULL;
    if (rear == NULL)
    {
        front = nptr;
        rear = nptr;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = nptr;
        rear = rear->next;
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = front;
    printf("\n");
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\t", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


void dequeue()
{
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nqueue is empty \n");
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *temp;
        temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        printf("\n\n%d deleted", temp->data);
        free(temp->data);
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ch;
    char n[256];

    do {
        printf("\n\nQueue Menu\n1. Add \n2. Remove\n3. Display\n0. Exit");
        printf("\nEnter Choice 0-3? : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter a name: ");
                scanf("%s", n);
                enqueue(n);
                break;
            case 2:
                dequeue();
                break;
            case 3:
                display();
                break;
        }
    }while (ch != 0);
}
```